# android custom suggestions won't show up

Tags: android

I read the documentation regarding search suggestions and i implemented almost everything.

it asks me to make a `content provider` and then return a `cursor` from its `query` method.

This is what i did:

```
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
        String[] mColumnNames={SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2, BaseColumns._ID};
        String query = uri.getLastPathSegment().toLowerCase(); //Logging gives me the string
        MatrixCursor matrixCursor=new MatrixCursor(mColumnNames);
        int i=0;
        for(Song song:songs){
            if(song.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(query)){
                matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{song.getTitle(),song.getArtist(),song.getId()});
            }
        }
        return matrixCursor;
    }
```

I logged `query` string and i am getting the log but i don't see any suggestions?

Do i have to make my own adapter or the default one is sufficient?

There is no mention of the views of the suggestions except it says that i have to return a cursor and two of the columns are mandatory.

am i missing something?

P.s:

- `getTitle()` & `getArtist()` returns `string`.
- `getId()` returns `long`

Update:

Changed the code and removed the looop.

```
String[] mColumnNames={SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2, BaseColumns._ID};
        String query = uri.getLastPathSegment().toLowerCase();
        MatrixCursor matrixCursor=new MatrixCursor(mColumnNames);
        matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{"asasas","aaa",(long)1});

        return matrixCursor;
```

This doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no body seems interested.

I found why it wasn't working.

The order of the columns need to be correct i.e. first and second column has to be `_id` and `SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1`

```
MatrixCursor mc=new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id",SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2});
```

This gave me the specified results on the search dialog.